# Change default mount group of USB drive in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, automount

I have a shared, family computer which has USB drives attached to it. Multiple users can be logged in, that sort of thing. All of the users have been added to "Access external storage devices automatically", however I've noticed that when one user plugs in a USB device, the other users can't see it without unmounting/remounting.

When a drive is mounted, it seems to mounted at:

```
drwx------  5 jdoe  jdoe   4096 2011-08-10 12:03 DriveName/
```

What I want to do is change the default mount group settings, to:

```
drwxrwx---  5 jdoe  family   4096 2011-08-10 12:03 DriveName/
```

I know I can do this through fstab, but as far as I know that forces you to name the drive/mount point and that's not what I'm looking for, what if a user adds a NEW usb device and wants it shared with the other users?

Comment: seriously? Nothing, also, does adding a comment bump?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are helpful. Nothing to be done about it now. :(

[How to set default permissions for automounted FAT drives in Ubuntu 9.10?](https://superuser.com/questions/134438/how-to-set-default-permissions-for-automounted-fat-drives-in-ubuntu-9-10)

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=586708